# Programmatically pan the Windows 10 UWP map control

Tags: windows, uwp, bing-maps, pinning, uwp-maps

Is there any event in the windows 10 UWP map control which can be used to pan programmatically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Do you want to add some pins in Bing maps?

Comment: I know Bing Maps aren't that great but Bin Map is a bit harsh :)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on the Windows 10 UWP map control can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642089.aspx

If you want to programmatically pan the map you can use the TrySetViewAsync method on the MapControl. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn637062.aspx